# Microsoft Word: Table of Contents ToC - bibliography appears bold

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I am working on a big scientific document lately and it turns out that the 'Bibliography' which is included in my Table of Contents (ToC) is in **BOLD** in the Table of Contents.

Certainly, I can highlight the 'Bibliography' inside the ToC and change it back to normal text, but every single time I update the ToC it is back to bold.

Any ideas how to change that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with corrupted styles, but not necessarily.
The problem could be with the bibliography in the document, because when
a TOC is generated, any explicit formatting is carried over to the TOC
as explicit formatting.

One way to test if this is the problem is to entirely select one bibliography entry
in the document (including any paragraph mark at the end) and press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.
The first returns the paragraph to the underlying character formatting as defined
in the style and the second returns the paragraph to the underlying paragraph
formatting defined in the style.

If after pressing these two shortcut keys the bibliography looks different than it
did before, then there was explicit formatting applied that would carry over and
affect the TOC that relies on that formatting.
Your shoulf repeat this process with all the bibliographies,
and only then (if required) make any changes to the styles.

Comment: Thank you that was really explicit! HOWEVER, perhaps my post was not clear enough. All the entires inside my Bibliography are well-formatted and are no tthe problem.

The actual word ' Bibliography ' is included in the ToC in order for the reader to know at which page the Bibliography resides.

All the other Level 1 entires in ToC are formatted as Heading Style 1, and even though they are **BOLD** in text, in the ToC they are not bold. The 'Bibliography' is also formatted as Heading Style 1, however it is both **BOLD** in text as well as inside the ToC.

Comment: When I change the formatting of the word 'Bibliography' in text from **BOLD** into normal, then it appears as normal in the ToC, however I want it to be **BOLD** in text and **NORMAL** in ToC and I have no idea what to do!

Comment: You can't tell Word not to reproduce non-style formatting in the TOC, but you may be able to shortcut the way by selecting the entire TOC and then enter Ctrl+Space and Ctrl+Q, to clear formatting from the TOC in one go.

Comment: If you toggle the field code, is there a switch ("\") indicating bold type? Also, try clearing the formatting from "Bibliography" and reapplying the style.